# How to skip scenarios in JBehave BDD

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I tried to skip the scenarios in JBehave BDD by adding

```
configuredEmbedder().useMetaFilters(Arrays.asList("-skip"));
```

in storyrunner and `Meta: @skip` tag in feature file, but not able to skip.
Please help.

Comment: the questions have been asked many time, please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21683139/not-able-to-skip-scenarios-in-jbehave-with-junitstory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34775239/how-to-skip-a-particular-scenario-on-jbehave-tests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926723/jbehave-maven-how-to-skip-scenario-tests